Why a ubuntu virtual machine hosted in GNS3 can ping but cannot access local services?
I am experiencing an issue where my Ubuntu 20.04.4 virtual machine is unable to access any locally hosted services within the same network. The services are running on various machines within the network, and I can access them from my PC without any problems.
Environment Details:
Web Server:
Hosted in Proxmox using Ubuntu container. Can be accessed from other devices on the network. No configuration made, just a clean install.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4
Web Server: Apache2
Apache Status: Active and listening on port 80

Virtual Machine:
Hosted in GNS3 and connected to the Cloud using a bridged adapter. Clean install of ubuntu, no configuration made.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4

Issue:
I can ping the local services from the VM, but they fail to load in a browser. Also commands like curl, telnet, wget fail to connect. However everything is working fine on a Windows PC that is on the same local network.
What could be the reason for this? Everything is a clean install and no other configurations have been made. Maybe someone could point me into the right direction for this.

Don't think ping working proves much. Your issue is establishing connection on port 80 (or is it targeting 443?). As other hosts can access Apache via port 80, something is preventing this one. When using cURL pass it the verbose flag, to see more details (if it's failing on port you won't see much either way). Something like:

curl -vIL host:port

Most likely one of the following is the issue:

Firewall terminating the connection
Bad routing

Try performing packet capture from both VMs (port 80 and 443) and check exactly on which part is it failing:

Packets not leaving the source host? Check local fw on that machine
Packets leaving source host but can't be seen on destination host? FW in between or routing
Packets can be seen coming to the destination host? Local firewall on that host could be the cause

